# Updating ImageView in Android

Tags: java, android

I am building a song player. The issue is with the ImageView for album art not getting updated for songs. When I play the first song, the ImageView is properly set. However when next songs get played, the ImageView isn't updated at all. Even when I play the same song after another song.
Here is my code:

The ImageView `album_art` and MediaPlayer `mp` are declared in the MusicPlayer class before `onCreate()`.

onCreate():

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   //other stuff
   album_art = findViewById(R.id.album_art);
   playSong(); //this method handles the song player
}
```

playSong():

```
public void playSong()
{
   //other stuff like initializing mp
   Bitmap art = getArt();
   Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(art, 125, 125, true);
   album_art.setImageBitmap(resized);
   nextSong(); //sets onCompleteListener
   mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
         mp.start();
      }
   });
}
```

nextSong()

```
public void nextSong()
{
   mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //set next song
                album_art.setImageDrawable(null);
            }
        });
}
```

What I tried so far:

1. Initializing `album_art` in `playSong()` and setting it to null in `nextSong()`.
2. Setting a non resized image in `playSong()`
3. Checked logs and verified that the `getArt()` function works perfectly.

None of these things were able to set the ImageView with the proper image after the first song.

Comment: Please check onCompletion() is working

Comment: Yes it works. The next song is played and the logs show that `getArt()` returns the correct image according to the song.

Comment: NO. I mean `onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)` worked?

Comment: Why are you setting album_art.setImageDrawable(null);?